# how to limit tag-it input in jquery

Tags: jquery, input, tags, limit, tag-it

How will I be able to limit the number of inputs a user can input from a Tag-It feature in jquery? I am currently using [this plugin](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/), but I would only want the user to be able to input 3 types of tag in an input box similar to our tags here at stack that limits the user to a maximum of 5 tags per question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tagLimit` options and set it to `5`

```
$("#myTags").tagit({
    tagLimit: 5
});
```

You can view more options from their docs **[here](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown)**